# Prove inflection point is maximum

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

I have found the function

$$f(x,k) = \frac{x^{p-k} a_k}{\sum_{i=0}^p (x^{p-i} a_i)}$$

, where $p>0, x>0, a_i>0$ for all $i$, has a turning-point at the value of $x$ which satisfies

$$\sum_{i=0}^p (i-k)x^{p-i}a_i = 0$$

From plotting $f(x,k)$ I know that in general this turning-point is a maximum. However, is there any way of proving this?

I was working on the algebra to get to the second derivative but then I realised it may not help -- the second derivative is not necessarily negative (for $x>0$) and no closed-form expression for the root of $\sum_{i=0}^p (i-k)x^{p-i}a_i = 0$ is possible, as it's a $p$-degree polynomial.